# How do you import AVI Files to iTunes?

Tags: itunes, mov, video

How do you import AVI Files to iTunes? I know there is a program that lets you do it and automatically names tv shows and stuff, but I cant think of the name, Does anyone know of a program that does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handbrake to covert to a compatible format.  You can fix the metadata in iTunes once you've imported it.

There are programs that will set the metadata based on the file name but unless you are planning to do many files, it may not be worth the trouble.  Are you using OS X or Windows?

Comment: OS X, and I found the program that does it, its called iFlicks :D

Comment: @WilliamL. Can you provide a link to iFlicks?